# how to autowire @bean classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have following `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {
    @Bean
    public BeanClass get() {
        return new BeanClass()
    }
}
```

Now I want to autowire BeanClass in some other class

```
public class SomeClass2 {
    @Autowired
    BeanClass beanCLass
}
```

Currently beanClass is coming null.
What and how exactly I need to tell spring for this autowiring.

Comment: That's pretty much all you need to do. Are you sure your Object is instantiated correctly? Also it would be easier to help you if you posted your actual code.

Comment: Seems you have little understanding of Spring. Nothing to do with question but i advice you to go through java brains spring tutorial.

Comment: At first you made mistake in the word Configuration. The second one is to register your packages in settings to enable opportunity of autowiring.

Comment: @jokernoel How to register the package is my question exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html#bean-naming)

> By default, the bean name will be that of the method name

`get` is your bean name, try with this configuration:

```
@Configurtion
public class SomeClass {
    @Bean
    public BeanClass beanCLass() {
        return new BeanClass()
    }
}
```

Bean

```
@Component
public class SomeClass2 {
    @Autowired
    BeanClass beanCLass
}
```

Comment: It should work even with the get name since spring will retrieve by type.

Answer (score 0):

Your SomeClass2 must be a spring bean. Annotate SomeClass2 with @Component.