# @Autowired @Bean from other class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

```
@Configuration
public class Class1 {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        ....
    }
}

@Component
public class Class2 {
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
```

And I still get:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

```
Could not autowire field: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl (path_of_where_autowiring); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The Class1 bean location is in `Package1` and the Class2 location is in `Package2`.

Why my bean is not found? Help

(Also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693540/how-to-autowire-bean-classes) but didn't helped me)

EDIT

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
    Implclass nsi = applicationContext.getBean(Implclass.class);
    nsi.the_method_here();
}
```

```
@Component
public class Implclass implements Implinterface {
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
    @Override
    public void the_method_here(){
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(sender);
        message.setTo(receiver);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content);

        mailSenderService.send(message);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfiguration {
   @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("some_property.file"));
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

EDIT (TREE)

```
x - src/main/java
  x -- package_1
    x - Class1
  x -- package_2
    x - Class2 (ImplClass)
```

Comment: How do you load `Class1`/Configurations?

Comment: @user7294900 edit added

Comment: Looks like your `@ComponentScan` doesn't work. Try to specify package to scan in it.

Comment: But does the problem is in here ```Could not autowire field: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl``` he's looking in this path, but not where bean is created in ```Class1```? @talex

Comment: It show what it looking for, not where. Your `Class1` and `Class2` is in different packages right?

Comment: @talex yes, they are in different packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@ComponentScan({"Package1", "Package2"})`

Comment: now it just gives me ```NoSuchBeanDefinitionException```in Package where the @Bean is not located.

Comment: now it says ```NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [path_to_Implclass] is defined```, which doesn't have ```@Bean``` (the class where I'm Autowiring)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with using different names.
Reference Link : https://dzone.com/articles/playing-sround-with-spring-bean-configuration

```
@Configuration
public class Class1 {
@Bean
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderWithInjection() {
    ....
}
}

@Component
public class Class2 {
@Autowired
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
}
```

Comment: This gives me the same ```NoSuchBeanDefinitionException```.

Answer (score 0):

you can use`@ComponentScan` 
or

```
 ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
 ctx.register(Config.class); // config 
 ctx.refresh();
// and try 
 Implclass nsi = ctx.getBean(Implclass.class);
```

Comment: I get even more ```classpath``` errors from registering the Config.class

Comment: what is the Exception after u register `Class1.java` ?

Comment: Correction: same no such bean exception```NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [path_to_Implclass] is defined```

Answer (score 0):

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext can take multiple configuration classes in the constructor. Can you try passing all the configuration files in the constructor as Step-1. Then it can be further debugged to better the solution.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class<?>... annotatedClasses)
```

e.g.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class1.class, Class2.class, SpringConfiguration.class);
```

**Also, where is your ImplClass, posting a tree structure would have been very helpful.**

Comment: I added the tree structure and I've added multiple classes (```ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class1.class,SpringConfiguration.class)```) and I get ```IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xxx.xxx.xxx' in string value "classpath:xxx.xml"```

Comment: You haven't added Class2.class in the constructor as per your comment. Can you also tell what these xxx are? Helps understand the problem.

Comment: xxx is just a file in the ```src/main/resources/SECURITY-INF```

Comment: And added both (where the ```@Bean``` is located and I ```@Autowired```) classes + SpringConfiguration.class. And I get the exception listed above.

Comment: Can you check in your code where are you referring to this property. And Does `some_property.file` have that property key and value pair? Assuming it's saved here `src/main/resources/some_property.file`

Comment: Yes, the ```some_propert.file``` contains this property which gives me this error. What is more, this value is imported in the ```xml``` file in ```src/main/resources/SECURITY-INF``` - ```<import resource="classpath:SECURITY-INF/${server.security.filename}.xml" />```

Comment: Although its possibly a type, but do check, is it `some_propert.file` or `some_property.file` And where is this file stored in project (folder path precisely)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194765/discussion-between-lpkej-and-himanshu-bhardwaj).